# How do I compile against Google APIs with gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Unfortunately I have an app stuck using the maps v1 APIs and need to compile the app against the Google APIs. I am using a newer version of the android gradle plugin (`com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+`) as well as gradle 1.10. I am attempting to compile against `Google APIs 16` and getting this error:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':compileReleaseJava'.
> failed to find target Google Inc.:Google APIs:16
```

In older versions (i.e. gradle 1.8 with gradle plugin `com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+`) I could do this in my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Google APIs:16"
    // rest of gradle file here
}
```

and it worked fine. However, if I set my compileSdkVersion to 16, I get compile errors because of all the v1 map apis my app is using. Is there a way to compile against the google apis with the newer gradle plugin like this?

Comment: Hi. Did you manage to solve this problem? I'm wondering if I should even bother in late 2017. Don't even know if the API key still works...

Comment: No I did not solve it. Eventually I moved on from the project.

Answer (score 0):

The error just looks like you did not download the Google API add-on for API 16.

Comment: I definitely have it installed. It works when I use the older version of the gradle plugin (0.6 or earlier). It's just that I want to use the latest version of the gradle plugin and I have a feeling support for the google apis was removed.

Comment: well it wasn't removed on purpose and I'm not sure why it wouldn't wor anymore. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Run Android SDK Manager then delete all content from API 16 and redownload it.